# cleaning up my understanding of Shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny

I have a project and I would like to start modularising my code in my Shiny App. I would like to get my head around a few things regarding modules.

1. I can pass the `UI` modules to the user interface without any issue `ui_MODULE` and `ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS`. My problem arises when I try to pass the server module to the App `server_location_dropdown_filter`. **How can I fix this issue?**
2. My modules are called `ui_MODULE("myMODUEL")` and `ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS("myMODULE2")` - I know the `myMODULE` and `myMODULE2` are passed to the `NS` but I am still having a little difficulty understanding how this part works intuitively - I thought we could reuse the modules by calling them again but this time passing a new `NS` to the module - i.e. in the App I pass `ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS("USE_AGAIN")` - but I do not get the location dropdowns again... **How can I correctly re-use the modules?**
3. I would like to understand a bit better how I can correctly modularise my projects. I read a lot about modules online but I find it easier to learn by applying it to my own code. Can you help modularise the following App?

Shiny App:

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reactable)

################ GENERATE DATA ##############################
# Define the US states and cities
us_states <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California")
alabama_cities <- c("Birmingham", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Montgomery", "Tuscaloosa")
alaska_cities <- c("Anchorage", "Fairbanks", "Juneau", "Sitka", "Wasilla")
arizona_cities <- c("Phoenix", "Tucson", "Mesa", "Chandler", "Scottsdale")
arkansas_cities <- c("Little Rock", "Fort Smith", "Fayetteville", "Springdale", "Jonesboro")
california_cities <- c("Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "San Diego", "San Jose", "Fresno")

# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate random price and quantity data
data <- tibble(
  state = sample(us_states, 5000, replace = TRUE),
  city = case_when(
    state == "Alabama" ~ sample(alabama_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE),
    state == "Alaska" ~ sample(alaska_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE),
    state == "Arizona" ~ sample(arizona_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE),
    state == "Arkansas" ~ sample(arkansas_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE),
    state == "California" ~ sample(california_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE)
  ),
  price = runif(5000, 10, 100),
  quantity = sample(1:10, 5000, replace = TRUE)
)
#############################################################

################# UI ###################

ui_MODULE <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    tags$div(
      class = "panel-header",
      numericInput("price", label = "Price?", value = 10, min = 1, step = 500),
      numericInput("quantity", label = "Quantity?", value = 10000, min = 1, step = 50),
      sliderInput("discount", label = "Discount", min = 0, max = 0.25, post  = " %", value = 0.08, step = 0.001),
      actionButton("compute", "Compute!")

    )
  )
}

################# UI LOCATIONS ###############
ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS = function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$div(
      class = "panel-header-locations",
      selectInput("stateSelect", label = "Select State Data", choices = c()),
      selectInput("citySelect", label = "Select City Variable", choices = c()),
    )
  )

}

################## SERVER MODUEL ############
# This doesn't work correctly...
server_location_dropdown_filter <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    # Changes with changes in the slider input

    updatedTable = reactive(
      data %>%
        filter(state == input$stateSelect) %>%
        filter(city == input$citySelect)
    )

    output$table = DT::renderDT({
      updatedTable()
    })
  })
}

############### FUNCTIONS ###################

myFUNCTION = function(interest){
  data %>%
    mutate(
      p_q = price * quantity,
      someOtherCalc = p_q*interest
      )
}

# myFUNCTION(0.08)

#############################################


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = 'minty'),
  #titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  navbarPage("App Title",
             tabPanel("Plot",
                      fluidPage(
                        fluidRow(
                          column(6,
                                 ##### UI #######
                                 ui_MODULE("myMODUEL")

                          ),
                          column(6,
                                 #### UI Locations ####
                                 ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS("myMODULE2")
                                 )
                        ),
                        fluidRow(
                          column(6,
                                 DT::DTOutput('table')
                                 ),
                          column(6,
                                 DT::DTOutput('newTableOUT')
                                 )
                        )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("use_UI_Again",
                      fluidPage(
                        fluidRow(
                          column(12,
                                 ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS("USE_AGAIN")
                                 )
                        )
                      )
                      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # (1) First observe the states unique values in the data
  observe({
    choices = data %>% select(state) %>% unique() %>% pull(state)

    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "stateSelect",
      choices = choices
    )
  })

  ## (2) ## The cities are then updated to reflect the states selection
  observeEvent(input$stateSelect,{

    choices = data %>% filter(state == input$stateSelect) %>% select(city) %>% unique() %>% pull(city)

    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "citySelect",
      choices = choices
    )
  })

  #server_location_dropdown_filter("myFILTERS") # here I can't get this working...so I have to run the updatedTable and output$table here
  updatedTable = reactive(
    data %>%
      filter(state == input$stateSelect) %>%
      filter(city == input$citySelect)
  )

  output$table = DT::renderDT({
    updatedTable()
  })

  # Now I want to update the table by using a function...

  newTable = reactive(
    updatedTable() %>%
      myFUNCTION(input$discount)
  )

  output$newTableOUT = DT::renderDT({
    newTable()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues. First, you need to use namespace (`ns`) for each inputID in the module UIs. Second, you need to define a server module to return the input variables from `ui_MODULE`. Lastly, if you wish to call a ui module again, you need to call the corresponding server module again.

Try this

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reactable)
library(DT)

################ GENERATE DATA ##############################
# Define the US states and cities
us_states <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California")
alabama_cities <- c("Birmingham", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Montgomery", "Tuscaloosa")
alaska_cities <- c("Anchorage", "Fairbanks", "Juneau", "Sitka", "Wasilla")
arizona_cities <- c("Phoenix", "Tucson", "Mesa", "Chandler", "Scottsdale")
arkansas_cities <- c("Little Rock", "Fort Smith", "Fayetteville", "Springdale", "Jonesboro")
california_cities <- c("Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "San Diego", "San Jose", "Fresno")

# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate random price and quantity data
data <- tibble(
  state = sample(us_states, 5000, replace = TRUE),
  city = case_when(
    state == "Alabama" ~ sample(alabama_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE),
    state == "Alaska" ~ sample(alaska_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE),
    state == "Arizona" ~ sample(arizona_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE),
    state == "Arkansas" ~ sample(arkansas_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE),
    state == "California" ~ sample(california_cities, 5000, replace = TRUE)
  ),
  price = runif(5000, 10, 100),
  quantity = sample(1:10, 5000, replace = TRUE)
)
#############################################################

################# UI ###################

ui_MODULE <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    tags$div(
      class = "panel-header",
      numericInput(ns("price"), label = "Price?", value = 10, min = 1, step = 500),
      numericInput(ns("quantity"), label = "Quantity?", value = 10000, min = 1, step = 50),
      sliderInput(ns("discount"), label = "Discount", min = 0, max = 0.25, post  = " %", value = 0.08, step = 0.001),
      actionButton(ns("compute"), "Compute!")
      
    )
  )
}

server_module <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    rv <- reactiveValues()
    observe({
      rv$price <- input$price
      rv$discount <- input$discount
      
    })
    return(rv)
  })
}

################# UI LOCATIONS ###############
ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS = function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$div(
      class = "panel-header-locations",
      selectInput(ns("stateSelect"), label = "Select State Data", choices = c()),
      selectInput(ns("citySelect"), label = "Select City Variable", choices = c()),
    )
  )
  
}

################## SERVER MODUEL ############
# This doesn't work correctly...
server_location_dropdown_filter <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    # Changes with changes in the slider input
    
    # (1) First observe the states unique values in the data
    observe({
      choices = data %>% select(state) %>% unique() %>% pull(state)
      
      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "stateSelect",
        choices = choices
      )
    })
    
    ## (2) ## The cities are then updated to reflect the states selection
    observeEvent(input$stateSelect,{
      
      choices = data %>% filter(state == input$stateSelect) %>% select(city) %>% unique() %>% pull(city)
      
      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "citySelect",
        choices = choices
      )
    })
    
    updatedTable = reactive(
      data %>%
        filter(state == input$stateSelect) %>%
        filter(city == input$citySelect)
    )
    
    return(updatedTable)

  })
}

############### FUNCTIONS ###################

myFUNCTION <- function(data,interest){  
  df <- data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(p_q = price * quantity)  %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
      someOtherCalc = p_q * interest
    )
  return(df)
}

# myFUNCTION(0.08)

#############################################


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = 'minty'),
  #titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  navbarPage("App Title",
             tabPanel("Plot",
                      fluidPage(
                        fluidRow(
                          column(6,
                                 ##### UI #######
                                 ui_MODULE("myMODULE")
                                 
                          ),
                          column(6,
                                 #### UI Locations ####
                                 ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS("myMODULE2")
                          )
                        ),
                        fluidRow(
                          column(6,
                                 DT::DTOutput('table')
                          ),
                          column(6,
                                 DT::DTOutput('newTableOUT')
                          )
                        )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("use_UI_Again",
                      fluidPage(
                        fluidRow(
                          column(6,
                                 ui_MODULE("USE_AGAIN")
                          ),
                          column(6,
                                 ui_MODULE_LOCATIONS("USE_AGAIN2")
                          )
                        ),
                        fluidRow(
                          column(6,
                                 DT::DTOutput('table2')
                          ),
                          column(6,
                                 DT::DTOutput('newTableOUT2')
                          )
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  updatedTable <- server_location_dropdown_filter("myMODULE2")
  
  output$table = DT::renderDT({
    updatedTable()
  })
  
  values <- server_module("myMODULE")
  
  newTable = reactive({
    req(updatedTable(),values$discount)
    myFUNCTION(updatedTable(),values$discount)
  })

  output$newTableOUT = DT::renderDT({
    newTable()
  })
  
  ### USE MODULES again
  
  updatedTable2 <- server_location_dropdown_filter("USE_AGAIN2")
  output$table2 = DT::renderDT(updatedTable2())
  
  values2 <- server_module("USE_AGAIN")
  
  newTable2 = reactive({
    req(updatedTable2(),values2$discount)
    myFUNCTION(updatedTable2(),values2$discount)
  })
  
  output$newTableOUT2 = DT::renderDT(newTable2())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @user113156, Please note that your second call does show the selectInputs in the tab `use_UI_Again`